# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'row'

Tags: python-3.7

```py
    import openpyxl as xl
    wb=xl.load_workbook("C:\\praveen\\python\\Excel\\Book1.xlsx")
    title_column_name="Name"
    ws=wb.active
    searchstring="joe"
    for row in list(ws.rows)[1:]:
        if row[1].value.find(searchstring)!= -1:
            print("found a matching row!slno={0}, name={1}, subject={2}, marks={3}".format(row[0].value, row[1].value, row[2].value. row[3].value))
```

Error output:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question in a way that makes sense to people that actually want to offer their help. My advice would be to give it some more context.

Comment: Please provide more info about error, sample data and also some context like what you are trying to achieve.