# AttributeError: 'workbook' object has no attribute 'max_row'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705411/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-row) here but it has no response.

Am using a public github package [here](https://github.com/Sydney-Informatics-Hub/copy_xlsx_styles) to copy all the formatting from one excel file to another excel file.

By formatting, I mean the color, font, freeze panes etc.

```
style_sheet = load_workbook(filename = 'sty1.xlsx')
data_sheet = load_workbook(filename = 'dat1.xlsx')
copy_styles(style_sheet, data_sheet) # the error happens in this line
```

The error producing line within copy_styles function is given below

```
def copy_styles(style_sheet, data_sheet):
    max_matched_row = min(style_sheet.max_row, data_sheet.max_row)
    max_matched_col = min(style_sheet.max_column, data_sheet.max_column)
```

The full copy_styles function can be found in this github link [here](https://github.com/Sydney-Informatics-Hub/copy_xlsx_styles/blob/master/copy_xlsx_styles.py)

The error that I encounter is given below

> AttributeError: 'workbook' object has no attribute 'max_row'

If you want a sample file to test, it can be found in this github issue [here](https://github.com/Sydney-Informatics-Hub/copy_xlsx_styles/issues/1)

Comment: Regarding your edit, why are you trying to get the max row from a *workbook*?

Comment: @BigBen - I updated the code. Now, you can see that it still throws similar error

Comment: Right, but a workbook doesn't have a max row, it's a sheet that would have a max row.

Comment: Without sheet name, how can I refer the sheet? Should I go back to my old code.

Comment: The readme for the library quite clearly states that it works with worksheet objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to copy the style of the first sheet in the workbook, you should do:

```py
copy_styles(style_sheet.sheet_by_index(0), data_sheet.sheet_by_index(0))
```

If you want to copy the style of all worksheets (assuming that they match), just loop over them:

```py
style_wb = open_workbook(filename = 'sty1.xlsx')
data_wb = open_workbook(filename = 'dat1.xlsx')

for sheet_from, sheet_to in zip(style_wb.sheets(), data_wb.sheets()):
    copy_styles(sheet_from, sheet_to)
```

I changed the variable names on the second example to make it clear that they are `workbook`s, not `sheet`s.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Did you get to try the code , meaning whether the format is copied?

Comment: did they copy the format to all sheets?

Comment: oh yeah, the full code is in github link that I gave. No worries, I will try. I thought may be you tried the package as well

Comment: Will mark the answer by tonight. Away from my desk now.

Comment: I tweaked your code a little bit - `for sheet_from, sheet_to in product(wb.worksheets, wb1.worksheets):
    print(sheet_from)
    print(sheet_to)
    copy_styles(sheet_from, sheet_to)`

Comment: but I think `.sheet()` mentioned in your code doesn't exist.

Comment: `product` is the cartesian product. Are you sure this is what you want? Also, I assumed you were using the `xlrd` package, so I used its API in my answer.

Comment: I used product because I want format from first sheet of 1st excel file (sheet 1 of 1st excel file) to be applied to multiple sheets of 2nd excel file (sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3 etc). So, am I right to use product for this use case?

Comment: No, in that case you have to loop only over the sheets of the second file. `product` will give you all the combinations between sheets of the first and second file (it will work as you expect if the first file has exactly one sheet, but it is not robust in case the first file changes)